# Way to find which program uses the internet

Tags: internet, monitor, system

is there any way to find which program uses the network and the bandwidth consumed. System monitor shows only ram ,cpu usage and overall bandwidth usage. i want fr individual program

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/103634/any-good-application-for-data-usage-monitor

Comment: any GUI package